# Integrate Adobe AIR With C++

Tags: c++, air, integrate

I'm learning *C++* and before this i was reading some tutorials in the internet of the [*Adobe AIR*](http://www.adobe.com/br/products/air/) development, but if *Adobe AIR* is so much easy to learn and *C++* is a very flexible and good language it's possible to integrate those two languages in a same project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's in the works.](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:FAQ)

For now, you use either JavaScript or ActionScript.

An alternative to AIR is [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop/). Its language choices are JavaScript, Ruby, and Python.

Comment: This will be a very big project!

Comment: Thanks, this Titanium is very good too, i'm going to search some apps that are developed with this project. Thanks!